# django tastypie - how to stop model creation when sending post request

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am doing like this:

```
def hydrate(self, bundle):
     manipulate data here
```

Now, based on the data, I want to check whether its already available or not. And want to create object if it doesnt exist already. Simply saying, want to do get_or_create.

Answer (score 2):

You have hardly any code so I don't know what your models etc are around it but I think what you're looking for is:

[Model.objects.get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

Comment: Tasypie creates objects automatically after receiving data. If the object already exists, it retuns error(bcoz of uniquenesss).Without returning error, I just want to return Ok. which means I skip creating object for that.

Comment: Why are you trying to create the object when that function would do it for you?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [super](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super), which lets you overwrite, extend or prepend any class's method by calling `super` on its `type`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by overriding the obj_create method and using get_or_create function:

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    ....
```

But that doesn't sound like a good idea. Create means create and return already existing data..

Comment: You'd also need to be very careful about related data